# EPL match with the longest injury time

Tags: football, trivia, english-premier-league

Which EPL match has had the longest injury time added at the end of 90 minutes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Longest additional time: 12 minutes 58 seconds (Arsenal v. West Ham United, 23 January 2013)

Here is the match report for the game from the [Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/football/2013/jan/23/arsenal-west-ham-premier-league). The time added on was due to an injury to the West Ham player Potts.

> The visitors' bleak evening was compounded when the substitute Danny
>   Potts was carried off wearing a neck brace after almost 10 minutes of
>   treatment, having lost consciousness in a sickening aerial collision
>   with Bacary Sagna. The West Ham manager, Sam Allardyce, reported that
>   Potts had "hit the ground like a dead weight" with the "double blow"
>   being the manner in which he landed on his head.

Answer (score 2):

A match between [Watford and Norwich](https://www.skysports.com/football/watford-vs-norwich/446517) on 21 January 2022 had 15 minutes of additional time at the end, though this was due to a temporary floodlight failure causing the match to be disrupted, rather than an actual injury.

> Play was suspended for 11 minutes owing to a floodlight failure [...] There were **15 minutes of stoppage time** as a result of the floodlight failure...

Incidentally, the very next day, a match between [Brentford and Wolverhampton](https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/60005893) had *19* minutes of additional time at the end of the first half, partly due to a collision between two Brentford players and partly due to a drone flying over the pitch that caused play to be halted. You asked for the longest additional time at the end of the *second* half, so this technically doesn't answer your question, but it's worth noting regardless.